# How to analyse object using reflection to find public fields in it and generate xml with a description of the object content from it?

Tags: java

I found in Oracle Java tutorial "Obtaining Field Types" thing called FieldSpy, but I don't really know how to use it. I need to save in xml file informations about public fields, it's content and class name, which created object. Can somebody give me some tips?

For example, giving this:

```java
    class AllThePrimitives {
        public int testInt = 3;
        public Integer integerTest = 91;
        public float floatingNumber = 1.1f;
        public Float floatingClass = 4.3f;
        public double doubleNumber = 22.22;
        public Double floatingDoubleClassNumber = 0.00001;
        public short veryShortNumber = 0;
        public Short anotherShortNumber = -2;
        public long megaLong = 1000000L;
        public Long megaLong2 = -1000000L;
        public boolean itsATrue = true;
        public Boolean someFalseBool = false;
        public char character = 'u';
        public Character charr = 'z';
        public String someStringText = "Some String Text...";
        public byte bajt = 45;
        public Byte bajjt = 78;
    }

    class NotSoPublicClass {
        private String thePrivateString = "I am private";
        public static int publicInt = 1;
        protected boolean safeFalse = false;
        String string = "String";

        void notAField() {
        }

        public void definitelyNotAField() {
        }

        public static short shortVariable = 1000;
        private int thePrivateInt = 52;
        static Boolean truBull = true;
        static Long longVariable = 10L;
        public static boolean unsafeTrue = true;
    }

    class Box {
        public Box(String c) {
            content = c;
        }

        public String content;
    }

    class BoxInTheBox {
        public static Box staticBox = new Box("Static electricity");
        private Box myBox = new Box("It's a secret...");
        protected Box safe = new Box("Safe");
        Box anotherBox = new Box("Nothing");
        public Box lastOfBoxes = new Box("Common box content");
    }

    class Chest {
        public Chest(Character c, Box b, String s) {
            symbol = c;
            needABoxInAChest = b;
            color = s;
        }

        public char symbol;
        public Box needABoxInAChest;
        public String color;
        private Integer unusedVariable;
        static int[] forbiddenObject = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
    }

    class Containerception {
        public Chest theChest = new Chest('o', new Box("I'm in chest!"), "Red");
        protected Chest theChest2 = new Chest('q', new Box("I'm in chest :("), "Violet");
        public Chest theChest3 = new Chest('w', new Box("I'm in chest???"), "Ultraviolet");
        public Box mysteryBox = new Box("Golden coin");
        private HashMap<String, Integer> hashmap;
    }

    class DummyClass {
    }

    class StackOfStacks {
        public StackOfStacks(Object wntgd) {
            weNeedToGoDeeper = wntgd;
        }

        protected Stack<Stack<String>> trueStackOfStacks = new Stack<Stack<String>>();
        public Object weNeedToGoDeeper;
    }
```

I need to get this:

```xml
AllThePrimitives.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<object>
  <className>AllThePrimitives</className>
  <classState>
    <testInt type="int">3</testInt>
    <integerTest type="Integer">91</integerTest>
    <floatingNumber type="float">1.1</floatingNumber>
    <floatingClass type="Float">4.3</floatingClass>
    <doubleNumber type="double">22.22</doubleNumber>
    <floatingDoubleClassNumber type="Double">1.0E-5</floatingDoubleClassNumber>
    <veryShortNumber type="short">0</veryShortNumber>
    <anotherShortNumber type="Short">-2</anotherShortNumber>
    <megaLong type="long">1000000</megaLong>
    <megaLong2 type="Long">-1000000</megaLong2>
    <itsATrue type="boolean">true</itsATrue>
    <someFalseBool type="Boolean">false</someFalseBool>
    <character type="char">u</character>
    <charr type="Character">z</charr>
    <someStringText type="String">Some String Text...</someStringText>
    <bajt type="byte">45</bajt>
    <bajjt type="Byte">78</bajjt>
  </classState>
</object>


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

NotSoPublicClass.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<object>
  <className>NotSoPublicClass</className>
  <classState>
    <publicInt type="int">1</publicInt>
    <shortVariable type="short">1000</shortVariable>
    <unsafeTrue type="boolean">true</unsafeTrue>
  </classState>
</object>/


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

BoxInTheBox.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<object>
  <className>BoxInTheBox</className>
  <classState>
    <staticBox type="Object">
      <className>Box</className>
      <classState>
        <content type="String">Static electricity</content>
      </classState>
    </staticBox>
    <lastOfBoxes type="Object">
      <className>Box</className>
      <classState>
        <content type="String">Common box content</content>
      </classState>
    </lastOfBoxes>
  </classState>
</object>


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Containerception.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<object>
  <className>Containerception</className>
  <classState>
    <theChest type="Object">
      <className>Chest</className>
      <classState>
        <symbol type="char">o</symbol>
        <needABoxInAChest type="Object">
          <className>Box</className>
          <classState>
            <content type="String">I'm in chest!</content>
          </classState>
        </needABoxInAChest>
        <color type="String">Red</color>
      </classState>
    </theChest>
    <theChest3 type="Object">
      <className>Chest</className>
      <classState>
        <symbol type="char">w</symbol>
        <needABoxInAChest type="Object">
          <className>Box</className>
          <classState>
            <content type="String">I'm in chest???</content>
          </classState>
        </needABoxInAChest>
        <color type="String">Ultraviolet</color>
      </classState>
    </theChest3>
    <mysteryBox type="Object">
      <className>Box</className>
      <classState>
        <content type="String">Golden coin</content>
      </classState>
    </mysteryBox>
  </classState>
</object>


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

StackOfStacks.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<object>
  <className>StackOfStacks</className>
  <classState>
    <weNeedToGoDeeper type="Object">
      <className>StackOfStacks</className>
      <classState>
        <weNeedToGoDeeper type="Object">
          <className>StackOfStacks</className>
          <classState>
            <weNeedToGoDeeper type="Object">
              <className>StackOfStacks</className>
              <classState>
                <weNeedToGoDeeper type="Object">
                  <className>StackOfStacks</className>
                  <classState>
                    <weNeedToGoDeeper type="Object">
                      <className>StackOfStacks</className>
                      <classState>
                        <weNeedToGoDeeper type="Object">
                          <className>DummyClass</className>
                          <classState/>
                        </weNeedToGoDeeper>
                      </classState>
                    </weNeedToGoDeeper>
                  </classState>
                </weNeedToGoDeeper>
              </classState>
            </weNeedToGoDeeper>
          </classState>
        </weNeedToGoDeeper>
      </classState>
    </weNeedToGoDeeper>
  </classState>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example:

```
   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

           Test t = new Test("string", 2);
           Class clazz = Class.forName(t.getClass().getName());
           for(Field f: clazz.getFields()){
               System.out.println(f);//will print only public field names
               System.out.println(f.get(t));//will get the value of the field in the given instance
           }
       }
   }

public class Test {

    public String a;
    public int b;

    public Test(String a,int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Fox generating xml see: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_create_document.htm

Comment: Thanks, it hepled a lot!
What in situation when I get reference to the object? It looks like this: Box@7ea987ac
I need to read data from this object as well and save it in XML file.

Comment: From
   class Box {
        public Box(String c) {
            content = c;
        }
        public String content;
    }

    class BoxInTheBox {
        public static Box staticBox = new Box("Static electricity");
        private Box myBox = new Box("It's a secret...");
        protected Box safe = new Box("Safe");
        Box anotherBox = new Box("Nothing");
        public Box lastOfBoxes = new Box("Common box content");
    }

Comment: I need to get this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<object>
  <className>BoxInTheBox</className>
  <classState>
    <staticBox type="Object">
      <className>Box</className>
      <classState>
        <content type="String">Static electricity</content>
      </classState>
    </staticBox>
    <lastOfBoxes type="Object">
      <className>Box</className>
      <classState>
        <content type="String">Common box content</content>
      </classState>
    </lastOfBoxes>
  </classState>
</object>

Comment: For each value you get do instanceof Object.
If it is true recursively call the the function that reads the object.
Be careful! if there is a loop between the objects you will get a infinite recursion, so keep track of the objects you have visited.